# Apply function into arr and print out

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy

```
def kiem_tra_so_hoan_chinh(so):
    if so <= 1:
        return False
    else:
        tong = 0
        for i in range(1, so):
            if so % i == 0:
                tong += i
        if tong == so:
            return True
        else:
            return False

         
        np.random.seed(5)
    arr1 = np.random.randint(low = 1, high = 101, size = 16) 
    arr1=arr1.reshape(4,4)
    arr1
```

How can I use the function into array and print out arr1 line if it contains perfect number
If I use `kiem_tra_so_hoan_chinh(arr1)`, it shows an error:

> "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**:

Use `np.vectorize` and `any` with list comprehension. Note: `np.vectorize` is just a fancy numpy `for-loop`

```
arr2 = arr1[[np.vectorize(kiem_tra_so_hoan_chinh)(i).any() for i in arr1],:]

Out[533]:
array([[74,  9, 63, 28],
       [16, 54, 81, 28]])
```

**Method 2:**

`np.vectorize` with `np.apply_along_axis`:

```
arr2 = arr1[np.apply_along_axis(np.vectorize(kiem_tra_so_hoan_chinh), 1, arr1)
              .any(1),:]

Out[540]:
array([[74,  9, 63, 28],
       [16, 54, 81, 28]])
```

**Method 3**:

`np.frompyfunc` with list comprehension:

```
arr2 = arr1[[np.frompyfunc(kiem_tra_so_hoan_chinh,1,1)(i).any() for i in arr1],:]

Out[545]:
array([[74,  9, 63, 28],
       [16, 54, 81, 28]])
```

Comment: @DinhTruongAnhPhuong: you are welcome. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this using list comprehension should do the trick.

```
def kiem_tra_so_hoan_chinh(so):
    if so <= 1:
        return False
    else:
        tong = 0
        for i in range(1, so):
            if so % i == 0:
                tong += i
        if tong == so:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
np.random.seed(5)
arr1 = np.random.randint(low = 1, high = 101, size = 16) 
# use iterator to apply function to each element
is_perfect = np.array([kiem_tra_so_hoan_chinh(i) for i in arr1])
is_perfect_reshaped=is_perfect.reshape(4,4)
# each element is now a row of 4, so apply sum(row)>0 to find
# at least one perfect number.
contains_perfect = np.array([sum(row)>0 for row in is_perfect_reshaped])
print(arr1.reshape(4,4))
print(is_perfect_reshaped)
print(contains_perfect)

[[100  79  62  17]
 [ 74   9  63  28]
 [ 31  81   8  77]
 [ 16  54  81  28]]
[[False False False False]
 [False False False  True]
 [False False False False]
 [False False False  True]]
[False  True False  True]
```

Comment: Can u give me a support, I need to print out the result like this [[ 74   9  63  28][ 16  54  81  28]].. I try this code result = np.where(contains_perfect == True)
result_arr=np.array([print(arr1[:,i]) for i in result])
Thr result_arr is 1D array not 2D array as I want

Comment: A couple of points:
- writing print inside a list comprehension is odd, create your object then print it. 
- you can reshape the 1D array to 2D using .reshape method on the array as you have done above 
Let me know here if you have any more challenges :)